# Script to fetch list of drives, and then find out top consuming folders/files in it and if delete text files in them

Tags: powershell

To get list of files I used:

```
Get-WMIObject -class Win32_logicaldisk | Sort-Object drivetype
```

To get top consuming files in a specific drive for eg_ `C:\` I tried:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\ | Sort-Object -Property name -Descending
```

How do I find out the *top consuming* files/folder in the drive and also delete any text files in them?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow! You appear to have forgotten to ask an actual question :-) Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the help center and review [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then come back and [update your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69272049/edit) as necessary

Comment: The `.Name` property has nothing to do with how much space the file occupies on disk..